# What's the best redux architecture for this kind of situation?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm working on an app and I don't know what's the best way to create a good redux in this basic situation... Actually, in my company, we can't normalize data (long story...).

Imagine 3 views :

1) Display a list of folders (fetch from API, so I have one reducer for this entity).

2) Display the details of one folder. In it, there is a list of another entity : cats. Also, you have a cats filter form.

3) Display a list of cats (the difference between second view is that you're not on folder details). You have a cats filter form too.

How can I manage cats state on the second and the third view ? Must I create an action "GET_CATS_FOR_FOLDER" for the second view and another action "GET_CATS" for the third (that's not a good practice I guess) ? Shall I find a solution to have one action to manage both ? Same question for the filter form which impact cats state...

Ty by advance !

Answer (score 1):

Could you just create different selectors that combine the data as you need?

```
export const getFolders = createSelector(...);

export const getFolder = createSelector(...);

export const getFolderWithCats = createSelector(...);

export const getCats = createSelector(...);
```

Comment: I agree that this would be the best way - for an example see https://blog.angularindepth.com/sharing-data-between-modules-is-peanuts-3f40fcb38dd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would complicate all of that with reducers, states, stores and such.

Create a service (singleton if you want to keep the state)

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService() {
  folders: { name: string, id: string, cats: any[] }[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('api/folders').subscribe(folders => this.folders = folders);
  }
}
```

Now you can simply use a router to display your views and get the IDs from your URL, being shaped like this : `/#/folders/10/cats/12`.